# TikZ - Block with no margin problem

Tags: margins, tikz-pic

I want to eliminate the margin and put a red retangle along the left margin. I have a white space with the code:

```
\newgeometry{top=0cm,bottom=0.0cm,left=0.0cm,right=0cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[red] (0,0) rectangle (1,29.7);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use `overlay,remember picture` and the anchors of the page.

```
\documentclass{article}
% not relevant for the solution
\usepackage{geometry}
\newgeometry{top=0cm,bottom=0.0cm,left=1cm,right=0cm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture] 
\fill[red] (current page.north west) rectangle ([xshift=1cm]current page.south west); 
\end{tikzpicture}

blub
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `\noindent`:

```
\newgeometry{top=0cm,bottom=0.0cm,left=0.0cm,right=0cm}
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\fill[red] (0,0) rectangle (1,29.7);
\end{tikzpicture}
```